# Do I need to create a new View to download a File stored in my ASP.NET MVC Webapp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I have an anchor tag on my Index.html page

```
/Views/Leader/Index.html
```

Which when clicked goes to a javascript file. From there I want to initiate a download of a File which is stored under

```
/Views/Leader/Data.csv
```

**Question 1:** Is this the best place to store it? Does it matter where I store it?
My goal is when the user clicks the  tag it initiates a download. I currently have a Controller that handles the Index view, and created an action called Data that returns a FileResult.

In my javascript I have a JSON call to the /Leader/Data which returns an error.

**Question 2:** Do I need to create a Data.cshtml page so I can get to that function?

Ideally I want the user to click the button and stay on the Index page but initiate the download of the file.

Comment: No, you don't need to make a Data.cshtml file. You just have have make a controller having return type FIileResult.